# Stripe Error Popup

Tags: stripe, payment, renewals

During a test of the system, I am trying to run the card and Test cards do not work as it says the link either test or live the stripe demo cards do not work. I have to test on my own card. I type all information in and I click the button upon doing so I am greeted with a popup that says error.  It is using stripe payment, and I added the extension in via file manager and also setup stripe with both API keys as well. I have install all apporiate extensions from CIVI as I logged into the System Check and fixed all that. Firewall, Stripe 6.6.3, Sweet Alert. The orignal issue was ajax

My New Error is Configuration error - unable to process paymentInten
[image]

Comment: there are several other 'required' extensions for stripe to work which you do not list above. can you edit your question to confirm what you have installed, and if missing any then try installing them as a first step

Comment: I have updated the question

Comment: anything in your System Status about Stripe webhooks etc?

Comment: Stripe Webhooks are fine. and I see them on the stripe page as well

Comment: I have logged in a couple days later and still get the same message.

Comment: there is a stripe channel here https://chat.civicrm.org/civicrm/channels/stripe

Comment: Did you happen to get a solution to this?

Answer (score 0):

Stripe requires 'CiviCRM access ajax API' permission for anonymous and authenticated users, could you check if they are in place?

Comment: I have changed it and will try to test

Comment: I tested the that option and Nothing still receiving the same error. I will wait for a chache refresh as well.

Answer (score 0):

The list of extensions you gave doesn't include "Payment Shared", aka "mjwshared".  Please install that, it's required for Stripe.